# FragmentPagerAdapter showing fragments wrongly in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I have an `ActionBarActivity` inside which I have a `ViewPager`. I expect to see four (first, second, third, four) fragments in four (first, second, third, fourth) pages.

**Problem:**

- I see the second fragment on the first page.
- I then move to the second page. Saw nothing.
- I then move back to the first page. Saw the second fragment.

In the `onCreate()` of the `ActionBarActvity`, I have:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mGoodArrayListOfWords); 
mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

This is how `MyPagerAdapter` looks:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> mWords;


    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> words) {
        super(fm);
        mWords = words;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        String specificWord = mWords.get(position);
        return MyFragment.newInstance(specificWord);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mWords.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mWords.get(position);
    }
}
```

I instantiated a `MyFragment` using a static factory method and I made the no-arg constructor private:

```
    public static MyFragment newInstance(String word) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("WORD", word);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    private MyFragment() {
        super();
    }
```

Moreover, in `onViewOnCreated()`, I get a handle to the fragment's list view, use the `LoaderManager` to `init()` a loader. I update the list view's adapter in `onLoadFinished()` of the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`.

I think the problem is due to the `Loader`s finish their jobs after the fragments' views have been created. Log when I expect two pages and two fragments:

```
04-01 23:15:55.707 D/DebugTag﹕ getItem called
04-01 23:15:55.717 D/DebugTag﹕ getItem called
04-01 23:15:55.717 D/DebugTag﹕ on view created called
04-01 23:15:55.797 D/DebugTag﹕ on view created called
04-01 23:15:56.157 D/DebugTag﹕ on load finished called
04-01 23:15:56.177 D/DebugTag﹕ on load finished called
```

Comment: I moved all the code in `onViewCreated` to `onCreateView`. And everything works.

Answer (score -1):

Extend `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as you're using `getItem()` method. If you want to keep it `FragmentPagerAdapter` override `instantiateItem()`.

Comment: I've tried also FragmentStatePagerAdapter; but it gives me the same behaviour.

Comment: Try overriding `instantiateItem()` and call your fragments from there

Comment: thx i suspect the problem is that when I am on the first page, I have a fragment with an empty list view, the content brought back by the first loader is then overridden by that brought back by the second loader...

Comment: I too face this problem .Have you resolved this issue ? @Jonas

Comment: @RakeshL Did you try moving things to `onCreateView`?